# how to align image view an textview to left and textview aligned center below image view

Tags: android

```
how to align image view and textview to left using relative layout and textview aligned center below image view with height and width wrap content.  

Below is my code:

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/CardViewManageAccount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/four"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Eight"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Eight"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/four">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/banklayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Eight"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Eight">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ImageLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/TwentyFive"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bankLogoImg"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/FiftyFour"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/FiftyFour"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bankAccountNumber"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accountTypeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bankLogoImg"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Eight"
            android:background="@drawable/rectanle_boarder"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Fifteen" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bankLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bankAccountNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/TwentyFive"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Eight"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ImageLayout"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text="xxxxxxxx2862"
            android:textSize="@dimen/TwentyFive" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bankNameText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bankAccountNumber"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/TwentyFive"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Two"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bankLogoImg"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Bank of Baroda"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Eighteen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bankCodeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bankNameText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bankNameText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/TwentyFive"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="BARJKJHS"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Eighteen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/upiLengthText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bankCodeText"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Two"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/TwentyFive"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Ten"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bankLogoImg"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="UPI PIN LENGTH :"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Eighteen" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/defaultBankTick"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TwentyFour"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TwentyFour"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/FiftyFive"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Thirty"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/FiftyFive"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/black_untick" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Below is my full code of the layout xml :
parent layout is Relative layout and i gave two layout in code that is image layout and bank layout and i need have image layout frist then bank layout and inside image layout i need to place imageview and below textview(center of image view)

How to implement this??

Comment: can you post screen how actually screen you want? - if not post rough drawing

Comment: you can put  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" for both your textview and imageview.

Comment: if my image with is 54dp i want texview to be placed center with width wrap content

Comment: i dont want image and teview to be aligned center, its should be aligned left

Comment: giving layout_below its coming to down but how to make it center of image view

Comment: Try with android:layout_width="wrap_content" and android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" in your RelativeLayout and android:layout_centerInParent="true" in your TextView

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/banklayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bankLogoImg"
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accountTypeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Hemavathi If this solved your problem then please mark it as correct for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

First align image view left to the textview using  `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/accountTypeText"` and then set textview in center using     `android:gravity="center"`

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/banklayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Eight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Eight">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bankLogoImg"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/FiftyFour"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/FiftyFour"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/accountTypeText"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bankAccountNumber"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/accountTypeText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bankLogoImg"
                    android:text=""
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectanle_boarder"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/Fifteen" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/FiftyFour"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/FiftyFour"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bankAccountNumber"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/accountTypeText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rectanle_boarder"
        android:textSize="@dimen/Fifteen"
        android:text="sdf" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bankLogoImg"
        android:layout_above="@+id/accountTypeText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```